# How to create .kube directory inside the Home directory on Mac?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, rke

We usually add the `Kubernetes` configuration file inside the `.kube` directory in our Home directory when we use either `Windows` or `Linux` operating systems.
But when I try to create a `.kube` directory on `Mac OS`, it says,

> You can't use a name that begins with the dot because these names are
> reserved for the system. Please choose another name.

How can I do this to put the k8s configuration file into it?

Comment: can you please clarify `it doesn't allow me to create it`? does it throw some errors?

Comment: It should be ok to create the dir, what is the error message you got?

Comment: You can't use a name that begins with the dot because these names are reserved for the system. Please choose another name.

That's the message I got.

Comment: @PapEr any answer?

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia any answer?

Comment: I will look into that

Comment: Does Krishna Chaurasia's comment answer your question ?
Additionally please remember that you can specify other kubeconfig files by setting the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable or by setting the `--kubeconfig` flag as described in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/).

Comment: @matt_j Thank you, it helps

Comment: try ‘mkdir ~/.kube’ in terminal.app

Comment: it works on the terminal and the .kube directory will automatically get created if you run minikube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the `.kube` directory using the terminal app on Mac and also noticed that the `.kube` directory can be created at any location on your Mac.

Even though you created it, it will not display in Finder. You have to open the Terminal and check its' availability using `ls` or `ls -la` commands.